# C# MVC 5 - Create a SelectList For Dates Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, selectlist

Im trying to create a SelectList for Dates, in format `MMMM/yyyy`, in the TEXT property and `yyyy-MM-dd` in the VALUE property.

Everything works good, but when I use this SelectList in a edit `option` and I have to fill the form to edit, the SELECTED property doesn't work and I don't know why...

My method to create the list is:

```
public SelectList GetSLDate(DateTime _dateLimit, DateTime? _selected = null)
{
    var list = new List<SelectItemList>();
    var date = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);

    int month = Math.Abs(12 * (_dateLimit.Year - date.Year) + (_dateLimit.Month - date.Month + 1));

    for (int m = (month - 1); m >= 0; m--)
    {
        var dateRef = date.AddMonths(m);

        list.Add(
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = dateRef.ToString("MMMM/yyyy"),
                Value = dateRef.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            }
        );

        return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", ((_selected == null) ? null : (((DateTime)_selected).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you creating `List<SelectListItem>` (which is all `@Html.DropDownList()` requires) and then unnecessarily converting it to `SelectList`. What do you mean _"the Selected property does not work"_? If you binding to a property in the view, then its the value of the property which determines what is selected (setting the value of selected is just ignored)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you when you say about the convert of the list in SelectList. I do that to make it clear the understanding... This list, I use to bind my DropDownListFor, like a "@Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.DateSelected, (SelectList)ViewBag.slDate, ":: Select ::", new { ... })"...

Comment: You can change the method to `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSLDate()` and just `return list;` Creating the `SelectList` is unnecessary extra overhead. In the view its `@Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.DateSelected, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.slDate, ..)` If the value of `DateSelected` matches one of the option values then it will be selected. However I suspect your issue that `DateSelected` is typeof `DateTime` which will not match a string in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd'` so the first option will always be selected.

Comment: It's a kind of weird... When I debug the code and check the "list" content, the specific item appears selected, but when I'll see the view, the dropdown doesn't mark the selected value... And I don't know why and I don't know what could be... PS: Thanks for the tip about overhead. I've already changed that.

Comment: Because your strongly binding to a property so the helper uses the value of the property to determine which option to display. If you have options with values (say) `2015-06-25` and `2015-06-26`, and the value of `DateSelected` was a string with the value `2015-06-26` then the second option will be selected - but its a `DateTime` which will have  a value (say) `06/26/2015 7:45:15 AM` which does not match one of the options so the first option will be selected (because something has to be).

Comment: Got that, but my 'SelectList' and my 'SelectedValue' both have the values in string format. As you can see on my method above, I convert the 'SelectedValue' in DateTime to String... I did try everything, but simply doesn't work! =(

Comment: No, you values are not the same. Look at the values of the options - they are in the format `"2015-06-26"` but you property has a value `"06/26/2015 7:45:15 AM"` - To test this, In you view, include `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.yourDate)` and compare the output with the values in the options.

Comment: Ok, but I'm converting the Date type to String in the same format 'yyyy-MM-dd'. So, if I have 2 differente dates in the same day/month/year, but with the differente times, when I'll convert their to string with the same format, the result will be the equals...

Comment: So long as the value your binding to matches exactly one of the values in the options (character for character) then that option will be selected. But why don't you just use a jquery plugin ( a month picker)?

Comment: Because I show to the user a DropDown with the text option equals a ("January/2015","February/2015",...) and, after the select, I take the value in a format ('2015-01-01','2015-02-01'), because I have to write this value in the database...

Answer (score 0):

When you create your SelectListItem, try setting the `Selected` property:

```
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = dateRef.ToString("MMMM/yyyy"),
            Value = dateRef.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            Selected = _selected == dateRef
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it, but doesn't work as well. When I debug the code, the property Selected appear as 'true' value, but is the same thing, doesn't work... "/